# Show that $\exp \begin{pmatrix} x & -y\\ y & x\end{pmatrix}= \exp(x) \begin{pmatrix} \cos y& -\sin y\\ \sin y& \cos y\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, matrix-exponential

> Show that $$\exp \begin{pmatrix}
> x & -y\\
> y & x\end{pmatrix}= \exp(x) \begin{pmatrix}
> \cos y& -\sin y\\
> \sin y& \cos y\end{pmatrix}$$
> for all $ x,y \in \mathbb{R} $.

---

My thought process is the following:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b\\
b & a\end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{cc}c & -d\\
d& c\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a+c & -(b+d)\\
b+d & a+c
\end{array}\right)$$

and

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & -b\\
b & a\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{cc}c & -d\\
d& c\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
ac-bd & -(ad+bc)\\
ad+bc & ac-bd
\end{array}\right).$$

Can I use this idea in my proof?

Comment: How did you define $\exp(A)$ where $A$ is a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** the matrix is diagonalize
$$
\mathbf{A} = \left(\matrix{x & -y \\ y & x}\right)
$$
e.g.
$$
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{P}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{P}^{-1}
$$
To do so we need to compute the eigenvalues
$$
\det(\lambda \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{A})
$$
which is
$$
(\lambda - x)(\lambda - x) - y \cdot (-y) = \lambda^2 -2x\lambda +x^2 + y^2 = 0
$$
thus
$$
\lambda = \frac{2x \pm \sqrt{4x^2 - 4(x^2 + y^2)}}{2} = \frac{2x \pm2iy}{2} = x \pm iy
$$
(if the eigenvalues are degenerate then we can not continue further)

compute the eigenvectors to create $\mathbf{P}$ and
$$
\mathbf{D} = \left(\matrix{x + iy & 0 \\ 0 & x - iy}\right)
$$
with this in place
$$
\exp(\mathbf{A}) = \mathbf{P}\exp(\mathbf{D})\mathbf{P}^{-1}
$$
where we have
$$
\exp(\mathbf{D}) = \left(\matrix{\exp(x + iy) & 0 \\ 0 & \exp(x - iy)}\right)
$$
then you need to pre/post multiply with the respective eigenvector matrices $\mathbf{P},\mathbf{P}^{-1}$.

notes: Please see [details for diagonalization and conditions](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-diagonalization)

Answer (score 4):

The map $M:\mathbb C\to \mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ defined by $z=x+iy\mapsto \left[\begin{array}{cc}x&-y\\y&x\end{array}\right]$ satisfies $M(z+w)=M(z)+M(w)$, $M(zw)=M(z)M(w)$ and $M(tz)=tM(w)$ for $z,w\in\mathbb C$ and $t\in\mathbb R$. This implies that also $M(\exp(z))=\exp(M(z))$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. For $z=x+iy$ we thus get from Euler's identity $e^{iy}=\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$
$$ \exp\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&-y\\y&x\end{array}\right]=\exp M(z)=M(\exp(z))=M(e^x(\cos(y)+i \sin(y))=e^x M(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))= e^x
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos(y)&-\sin(y)\\\sin(y)&\cos(y)\end{array}\right].$$

Answer (score 4):

The argument of the exponential on the LHS
$$\begin{pmatrix} x & -y\\ y & x\end{pmatrix} \;=\;
 x\,\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \;+\; y\,\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}$$
may be identified with the complex number $\,x+y\,i\,$
because the matrix summands on the RHS commute and
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1& 0\end{pmatrix}^2 \;=\; -\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\,.$$
Under this correspondence we have
$\:\begin{pmatrix} \cos y& -\sin y\\ \sin y& \cos y\end{pmatrix}
\;\longleftrightarrow\;\cos y +i\sin y\,,\,$ and
the identity under consideration is just Euler's identity
$$e^{x+iy} \;=\; e^x\,(\cos y +i\sin y)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to diagonalise the matrix first, and then it should be easy from there. Expand in power series.

Answer (score 0):

Any analytic function of an $n\times n$ matrix is equal to a polynomial of degree $(n-1)$ with scalar coefficients:
$$
\exp \mathbf{A} 
= \beta_0 \mathbf{I}+
\beta_1 \mathbf{A}
$$
The eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ are known to be
$\lambda_k=x\pm iy$
and verify $
\exp(\lambda_k)
= \beta_0 + \beta_1 \lambda_k
$

It follows after straightforward manipulations
\begin{eqnarray}
e^x \cos y &=& \beta_0 + \beta_1 x \\
e^x \sin y &=& \beta_1 y
\end{eqnarray}
from which $\beta_0, \beta_1$ are easily found and thus the final relation .